# Onclick for each button add/remove class from attribute to HTML document

Tags: html, jquery

I have 2 buttons for now as an example. The problem here is, when I click on Button A for example it changes the class on the html document with the value from "data-accent-switcher" which in this case is BLUE, but when I press on button A again it changes with the value from button B, same happens with button b. Now even If I press like 20 times on Button A, I always want to have that value of from the data attribute (data-accent-switcher).

How can I make it possible?

```
<button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="blue">Button A</button>
<button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="yellow">Button B</button>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accentSwitcher').on("click", function() {
      var accentValue = $(this).data('accent-switcher');
      if (document['documentElement']['classList']['contains']('accent-blue')) {
        document['documentElement']['classList']['remove']('accent-blue');
        document['documentElement']['classList']['add']('accent-yellow');
      } else {
        if (document['documentElement']['classList']['contains']('accent-yellow')) {
          document['documentElement']['classList']['remove']('accent-yellow');
          document['documentElement']['classList']['add']('accent-blue');
        }
      }
      ips['utils']['cookie']['set']('ipsTheme_type', accentValue, true)
    });
  });
</script>
```

I've tried with if statements but obviously I'm wrong and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// a named function to handle the 'accent-switching', declared using
// Arrow function syntax, and taking one argument 'evt', a reference
// to the Event object passed automatically from the later use of
// EventTarget.addEventListener():
const accentSwitch = (evt) => {
    // we use destructuring assignment to retrieve the
    // currentTarget node (the node to which the function
    // was bound) from the Event Object:
    let {
      currentTarget
    } = evt,
    // we cache the data-accent-switcher attribute-value,
    // using the HTMLElement.dataset API:
    value = currentTarget.dataset.accentSwitcher,
    // we cache a reference to the element we wish to
    // affect (obviously, this could be changed to select
    // the appropriate ancestor element of your choice,
    // up to, and including, the <html> element):
    targetElement = currentTarget.closest('section');
    // if we have a variable called 'accentChoices', and
    // it holds a truthy value:
    if (accentChoices) {
      // we take the targetElement, and use the Element.classList
      // API to remove the list of classes from the element:
      targetElement.classList.remove(...accentChoices);
    }
    // here we again use the Element.classList API, this
    // time to add a class-name:
    currentTarget.closest('section').classList.add(value);
  },
  // using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve a NodeList of
  // all elements that have the class of 'accentSwitcher'
  // and also have a 'data-accent-switcher' attribute:
  accentButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.accentSwitcher[data-accent-switcher]'),

  // here we convert that iterable NodeList to an Array and then
  // use Array.prototype.map() to create a new Array based upon
  // the first:
  accentChoices = Array.from(accentButtons).map(
    // using an Arrow function, we use the
    // HTMLElement.dataset API to retrieve
    // the attribute-value of the data-*
    // attribute:
    (el) => el.dataset.accentSwitcher
  );

// iterating over the NodeList of elements we found,
// using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
accentButtons.forEach(
  // using an Arrow function to bind the accentSwitch()
  // function - note the deliberate lack of parentheses -
  // as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
  (el) => el.addEventListener('click', accentSwitch)
);
```

```css
:root {
  --blue: hsl(200deg 90% 70% / 1);
  --purple: hsl(300deg 90% 70% / 1);
  --yellow: hsl(60deg 90% 70% / 1);
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-block-size: 100vh;
}

main {
  block-size: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      135deg,
      #ffff,
      #fff7
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent 0 0.75rem,
      var(--colorChoice, var(--purple)) 0.75rem 1rem
    );
  box-shadow:
    0.75rem 0.75rem 1.5rem var(--colorChoice, var(--purple)),
    -0.75rem -0.75rem 1.5rem var(--colorChoice, var(--purple));
  display: flex;
  inline-size: clamp(15rem, 40%, 800px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  outline: 3px solid var(--purple);
  padding-block: 1em;
  padding-inline: 2em;
}

section.blue {
  --colorChoice: var(--blue);
}

section.yellow {
  --colorChoice: var(--yellow);
}

button {
  padding-block: 0.5rem;
  padding-inline: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- your HTML was adjusted primarily to wrap the <button> elements,
     and show an ancestor element that could be easily targeted via
     JavaScript, while providing some aesthetic hooks for the CSS: -->
<main>
  <section class="wrapper">
    <button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="blue">Button A</button>
    <button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="yellow">Button B</button>
  </section>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kwxb76L1/).

As OP wishes to continue using jQuery, I've added jQuery option below, again this has explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// creating a const variable to hold the collection of
// <button> elements:
const buttons = $('.accentSwitcher[data-accent-switcher]'),
            // creating an Array from the <button> collection:
          accentSwitches = buttons.map(function() {
        // returning the data-accent-switcher attribute-
        // value, using the data() method:
        return $(this).data('accent-switcher');
      // converting the modified collection into
      // a plain JavaScript Array with get():
      }).get();

// using on() to bind the anonymous function of the
// method as the event-handler for 'clicke' events:
buttons.on('click', function() {
    // caching the attribute-value of the
  // data-accent-switcher value:
    let accentChoice = $(this).data('accent-switcher')
  // navigating to the closest ancestor <section>
  // element:
  $(this).closest('section')
    // removing all the classes that are featured
    // in the Array of accentSwitches:
    .removeClass(accentSwitches)
    // adding the data-accent-switcher attribute-
    // value to the current element:
    .addClass(accentChoice)
    // using the css() method to update the
    // --colorChoice css custom property:
    .css('--colorChoice',
        // we're setting the above property to
      // the value held in the current <button>
      // element's own --colorChoice
      // custom property:
        $(this).css(`--colorChoice`)
    );
});
```

```css
:root {
  --purple: hsl(300deg 90% 70% / 1);
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-block-size: 100vh;
}

main {
  block-size: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      135deg,
        #ffff,
        #fff7
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
        transparent 0 0.75rem,
        var(--colorChoice, var(--purple)) 0.75rem 1rem
    );
  box-shadow:
    0.75rem 0.75rem 1.5rem var(--colorChoice, var(--purple)),
    -0.75rem -0.75rem 1.5rem var(--colorChoice, var(--purple));
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  inline-size: clamp(15rem, 40%, 800px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  outline: 3px solid var(--purple);
  padding-block: 1em;
  padding-inline: 2em;
}

button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-block: 0.5rem;
  padding-inline: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- your HTML was adjusted primarily to wrap the <button> elements,
     and show an ancestor element that could be easily targeted via
     JavaScript, while providing some aesthetic hooks for the CSS: -->
<main>
  <section class="wrapper">
    <button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="blue" style="--colorChoice: hsl(200deg 90% 70% / 1);">Button A</button>
    <button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="yellow" style="--colorChoice: hsl(60deg 100% 50% / 1);">Button B</button>
    <button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="green" style="--colorChoice: hsl(100deg 90% 70% / 1);">Button C</button>
    <button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="pink" style="--colorChoice: hsl(330deg 95% 70% / 1);">Button D</button>
    <button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="orange" style="--colorChoice: hsl(25deg 100% 50% / 1);">Button E</button>
    <button class='ipsButton accentSwitcher' data-accent-switcher="red" style="--colorChoice: hsl(355deg 90% 70% / 1);">Button F</button>
  </section>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kwxb76L1/1/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`[attribute]` selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
  - [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).
  - [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
  - [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`hsl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl).
  - [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
  - [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient).
  - [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
  - [`repeating-linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/repeating-linear-gradient).
- HTML:

  - [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
  - [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass).
  - [`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).
  - [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: Well. Thanks. But I would like the keep it in jQuery and the same code. Only 1 thing bothers me right now @BahrulRozak gave me a pretty nice solution to it but now this bothers me "what if I have like 10 buttons? Do I need to always add an else-if statement?"

Comment: "*I would like the keep it in jQuery*" - why? jQuery is - in most cases - not necessary, though it's obviously your prerogative to use it if you wish. As for "*what if I have like 10 buttons...*" - there are no `if` statements in my answer, and the linked demo shows a larger number of `<button>` elements in use, again: without `if` statements. So, no: you don't need to use any.

Comment: I agree with you. But I'm used to jQuery and I like to work with it. It's my preference so to say. I'm not trying to be rude or anything I do appreciate your help and your time invested into that code. If I could upvote it I would. I can see you are very invested in helping other on stackoverflow. Keep it up!!! I'm so sorry again :(

Comment: For sure others will use your code when searching for something similar like me.

Comment: And to be honest. Not gonna lie, I don't understand that code as easily with jQuery. In jQuery the code looks so much cleaner but in js, it looks like a mess :P That's why I said, "It's my preference".

Comment: @AlexandruMiclea: that's okay! I do this because I enjoy it, *not* because I want everyone to yield to my preferred way of doing things :)  I've edited the answer, to add a jQuery approach. Hopefully that should answer your question?

Comment: Thank you. I used your code. I did `$(this).closest(document.documentElement)` this instead of the closest section. It works but I hope is not wrong how I used it :D

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to have helped! As for using a different ancestor element, that's absolutely fine

Comment: `$("html").attr("data-accent", accentChoice);` I did it like this. But your code helped 50/60% of my problems. So thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @DavidThomas
I used his code and came up with this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    const accentButtons = $('.accentSwitcher[data-accent-switcher]'),
          accentSwitches = accentButtons.map(function() {
            return $(this).data('accent-switcher');
          }).get();
    accentButtons.on('click', function() {
      let accentChoice = $(this).data('accent-switcher')
      $(this).closest(document.documentElement)
        .removeClass(accentSwitches)
        .addClass(accentChoice)
      ips.utils.cookie.set('ipsTheme_type', accentChoice, true);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I hope this is right. But I'm not sure about this `$(this).closest(document.documentElement)`